# Database insertions not working and not giving any errors

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot insert the data into the database, I get no errors at all yet the table still appears empty.

I am using WAMP for development.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Below my code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "admin";
    $password = "admin";
    $dbname = "cookies";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if (!$conn) {
       die(mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    function test_input($data) { 
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
    }

    $nombre = test_input($_SESSION["nombre"]);
    $telefono = test_input($_SESSION["telefono"]);
    $entrega = test_input($_SESSION["entrega"]);
    $fecha_entrega = test_input($_SESSION["fecha_entrega"]);
    $direccion = test_input($_SESSION["direccion"]);
    $prod = test_input($_SESSION["prod"]);
    $cant = test_input($_SESSION["cant"]);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ventas (prod, cant, nombre, telefono, direccion, fecha_entrega) VALUES ('$prod', '$cant', '$nombre, $telefono', '$direccion', '$fecha_entrega')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: You should check the result of your query: `if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) echo mysqli_error($conn);`

Comment: thanks to you too Nick, i read Claudio's response first but yours would have been as right as his.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the errors of a `mysqli_query()` with the function `mysqli_error()`.

For development purpose, you can add it in your code, i.e., `mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or exit(mysqli_error($conn));` in order to see the errors reported by your database.

Remove it later, if you plan to publish your application, otherwise the errors from your database will be exposed to users.

Comment: I agree SQL errors should not be exposed to users, but one can use `error_log()` so the SQL errors go into the http log, so site admins can see it.

Comment: Your suggestion helped me solving it, there were two issues, the first one was missing ' ' in some of the fields in the value and also one of the fields was too long for the db column, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this , works fine

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO ventas (prod, cant, nombre, telefono, direccion, fecha_entrega) VALUES ('$prod', '$cant', '$nombre', '$telefono', '$direccion', '$fecha_entrega')";
```